# WndProc handler is inefficient

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the following handler of WndProc in my form. It should prevent moving the form horizontally (allowing to move only vertically):

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    if (!ShowCaption && m.Msg == 0x216)
    {  // Trap WM_MOVING
        var rc = (RECT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(RECT));
        int w = rc.right - rc.left;
        rc.left = this.Left;
        rc.right = rc.left + w;
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(rc, m.LParam, false);
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

It works but when user moves the form CPU usage increases very significantly. What could be so inefficient in this function and are there any ways to?

Comment: High CPU usage isn't necesarily a bad thing. Is is actually a problem, or why are you looking the CPU usage? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/03/10097861.aspx

Comment: It is really a problem: it causes other process hanging

Comment: Attribution is required at this site.

Comment: I would think that Marshal.* isn't very efficient, so calling it lots and lots of times per second (which occurs in your case) might be causing CPU use peaks.

Comment: @Mattias: high CPU usage isn't a bad thing **if you're doing something CPU-intensive**. Most apps aren't, and so most apps shouldn't hog the CPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code, and it works well. It didn't saturated 100% CPU as you said, only took ~16%.

I suppose that what is taking a long time to process, is the drawing of your form, or the drawing of your background windows (and not the wndproc implementation).

Try limiting the amount of redraws that your form can do per second by adding a wait

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
```

after this line:

```
Marshal.StructureToPtr(rc, m.LParam, false);
```

Sleeping 10 ms while dragging limits your form from redrawing more than 100 times per second, while leaving some CPU unused...

EDIT: Forgot to mention that adding the sleep changed the ~16% to ~12% on my box.

Answer (score 2):

You could just swallow the message if you don't call base.WndProc in your If block

```
if (!ShowCaption && m.Msg == 0x216)
{
    // Trap WM_MOVING
}
else
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Another solution (works quite well but somethimes flickers)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int initialX;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initialX = this.Location.X;
    }

    private void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Location.X != initialX)
            this.Location = new Point(initialX, this.Location.Y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm... Looks like it doesn't help